# removed large files from git repo; repo still humongous

Tags: git

I have, over the course of the last few days, removed several hundred megs of large text and binary files from a git repository that I had set up recently (I am relatively new to git).

I did this in order to reduce the amount of time it takes to clone this repository on a remote machine.

However, the repo itself is still huge, and it still takes forever to clone.  I suspect that git is keeping some manifestation of the large files in order to maintain some history.

How might I remove these objects, to make my repository "lean and mean"?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/198538/using-git-for-backup-how-to-permanently-remove-deleted-files-from-old-revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the history that contains those large files. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160208235904/http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) blog post on the subject.

Comment: the link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

Please try following command.

```
git gc --aggressive
```