# Using GIT for backup. How to permanently remove deleted files from old revisions?

Tags: backup, git

I'm using git for keeping all my sites backup here.
It works very well, I can jump in and out of a expecific backup with a command.

The problem is, this is incremental. Even if I exclude a file now, it will still be there in the old revisions. This is good, but there are some big files, like sql backups, that I dont need to keep all the history.

As I backup my database everyday, in a different file name, I'm running out of space =p

How can I permanently remove old/deleted files from my git repository?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/190771/removed-large-files-from-git-repo-repo-still-humongous) with a good link to an outside resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use git filter-branch. An example from the manpage:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

Comment: does it take a regular expression as filename?

Comment: You could use something like `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'find . -regex <regex> -print0 | xargs -r0 rm' HEAD` for that. (I don't like `-exec` ;)

Comment: oh that worked :) It didnt free as much space as I was thinking, but its better than nothing =p

Comment: If repository size is what you're after, you should go through the "Checklist for Shrinking a Repository" in the `git-filter-branch` manpage.